How to invoke a tool defined with zodFunction?
OpenAI exports function zodFunction:
import { zodFunction } from 'openai/helpers/zod';

It is used to create tools, e.g.,
const webSearch = zodFunction({
  description:
    'Search the web for information. Useful for when you need to answer questions about current events or a specific topic. The answer includes sources, which must be referenced in the answer using markdown footnotes.',
  function: async ({ query }) => {
    try {
      return await search({ query });
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof NoResultsError) {
        return 'No results found';
      }

      throw error;
    }
  },
  name: 'searchWeb',
  parameters: z.object({
    query: z
      .string()
      .describe(
        'The query to search for. Phrased in natural language as a question.',
      ),
  }),
});

How do I validate the function parameters now and/or invoke the actual tool?
I have discovered these properties, but they appear to be for internal use:
const args = matchingTool.$parseRaw(toolCall.function.arguments);
const result = await matchingTool.$callback(args);

